# C++: why base object is not accessible inside derived class if protected

Tags: c++, object, radix

Am a newbie to C++.

```
class A 
{
    public:
        int i;
    protected: //**--- [1]**
        void set()
        {
            i=5;
            cout<<i;
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        void call()
        {
            A obj;
            obj.set(); //**----[2]**
            set(); //**---[3]**
        }
};

int main()
{
    B* b_obj = new B;
    b_obj->call();
}
```

Why doesn't the code compiled if i try including **[2]** and not replacing **[1]** to public BUT it works if i compile including **[3]** alone?

Compiled error: error: ‘void A::set()’ is protected.

In short, My intention is to understand why base object cannot be called in derived class if the access specifier for the base class interface is set as protected.

Comment: I believe `A` is `Pet` and `B` is `Dog`, but it's a wild guess. @OP - please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if my answer is correct, but here goes:

set is protected in class A. This means no outside member can access set, but derived classes can.

When calling set() by itself inside B you are calling the function as a derived function from A inside your derived class B, meaning the compiler will accept this because the function is protected (accessible to derived classes.)

However when you define A obj, calling obj.set(), in relation to the obj instance, the call is external to the class, hence why the compiler gives error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Pet` is *unrelated* to `A` or `B`, so whether `f.set()` is allowed depends on the definition of `Pet`. By contrast, just `set()` works because it's protected in the base class, and hence accessible in derived classes.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistakes. now rectified.